# Issue with this.variable

Tags: jquery

I am looking for a way to give `div.rune.iXXX`/`div.rune.i +index` an integer which will be limited to itself, but then called upon by a child within itself.

layout: `...-container -> div.rune.i +index -> p`

Here is the section of jQuery that I am having issues with...

```
jQuery("body").on("click", "td", function() {
    if($(this).is('td.entry-name') || $(this).is('td.icon')) {
        if(!this.i){this.i = 0;} //<--- Issue here
        var getText = $(this).siblings('td.index').text();
        var getType = $(this).siblings('td.type').text();
        console.log(getText); //ID Check
        $.getJSON("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/4.14.2/data/en_US/rune.json", function(response){
            $.each(response.data, function (index, entry) {
                if(index == getText) {
                    console.log(entry.name); //Name Check
                    if(getType == "Mark") {
                        if($('div.mark-container').children('div.rune.i' +index).length > 0) {
                            this.i++;                               
                            $('div.rune.i' +index+ ' p').text('x' +this.i);  //<--- Issue here
                        } else {
                            $('div.mark-container').append('\
                            <div class="rune i' +index+ '" \
                            style="background:url(./assets/runes/rune0.png) -' +entry.image.x+ 'px -' +entry.image.y+ 'px no-repeat"><p></p></div>');
                        };
                    } else if(getType == "Seal") {
                        if($('div.seal-container').children('div.rune.i' +index).length > 0) {
                            this.i++;                               
                            $('div.rune.i' +index+ ' p').text('x' +this.i);
                        } else {
                            $('div.seal-container').append('\
                            <div class="rune i' +index+ '" \
                            style="background:url(./assets/runes/rune0.png) -' +entry.image.x+ 'px -' +entry.image.y+ 'px no-repeat"><p></p></div>');
                        };
                    } else if(getType == "Glyph") {
                        if($('div.glyph-container').children('div.rune.i' +index).length > 0) {
                            this.i++;                               
                            $('div.rune.i' +index+ ' p').text('x' +this.i);
                        } else {
                            $('div.glyph-container').append('\
                            <div class="rune i' +index+ '" \
                            style="background:url(./assets/runes/rune0.png) -' +entry.image.x+ 'px -' +entry.image.y+ 'px no-repeat"><p></p></div>');
                        }
                    } else if(getType == "Quint") {
                        if($('div.quint-container').children('div.rune.i' +index).length > 0) {
                            this.i++;                               
                            $('div.rune.i' +index+ ' p').text('x' +this.i);
                        } else {
                            $('div.quint-container').append('\
                            <div class="rune i' +index+ '" \
                            style="background:url(./assets/runes/rune0.png) -' +entry.image.x+ 'px -' +entry.image.y+ 'px no-repeat"><p></p></div>');
                        };
                    };
                };
            });
        });
    };
});
```

[Here is the rest of the code](http://jsfiddle.net/SaiyanToaster/faksa7bj/1/). I am not really sure how to describe the issue, but when you select something from the list to the left, it'll appear in the container to the right, if you try to add that item again it should add a `xINT` to the item on the right, setting it as a multiple. But currently the response you get is a `xNaN`.

**tl;dr:** I need to give the parent of `p` a variable that only applies to itself, then to be called by the child to add to itself and display itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `this` is called inside the `each` loop and doesn't refer to the element that was clicked outside of it. Save `this` to a new variable before going into the each-loop as in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/faksa7bj/3/) and it should work fine

```
       var thisThing = this;
        $.getJSON("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/4.14.2/data/en_US/rune.json", function(response){
            $.each(response.data, function (index, entry) {
                if(index == getText) {
                    console.log(entry.name); //Name Check
                    if(getType == "Mark") {
                        if($('div.mark-container').children('div.rune.i' +index).length > 0) {
                            thisThing.i++;                              
                            $('div.rune.i' +index+ ' p').text('x' +thisThing.i);
                        } else {
                            $('div.mark-container').append('\
                            <div class="rune i' +index+ '" \
                            style="background:url(./assets/runes/rune0.png) -' +entry.image.x+ 'px -' +entry.image.y+ 'px no-repeat"><p></p></div>');
                        };
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get `.i` value of incorrect object. In

```
$.each(response.data, function (index, entry) {}
```

function `this` points to another objects. So it should be something like:

```
if(!this.i){this.i = 1;}
var thisEl = this;
```

and later:

```
thisEl.i++;                             
$('div.rune.i' +index+ ' p').text('x' +thisEl.i);
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/faksa7bj/2/).